# Accelerating frame of reference, fermions and probability conservation

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, unruh-effect

I'm looking at solutions to the massless Dirac equation in an accelerating frame of reference in $(1+1)$-dimensions but the wave functions I get appear to violate probability conservation.

My accelerating (Rindler) coordinates are defined through
$$
t= X \sinh(\alpha T), \quad x = X \cosh(\alpha T),
$$
$$
T= \frac{1}{\alpha} \text{artanh}\left(\frac{t}{x}\right), \quad X = \sqrt{x^2 - t^2},
$$
$$
ds^2 = dt^2 - dx^2 = (\alpha X)^2 dT^2 - dX^2 . 
$$

Here's how I get my solutions.
I will use $\gamma^{\mu}=(\gamma^0,\gamma^1)=(\sigma_1, i \sigma_2)$ so that I the Dirac equation is (I've used the form from general relativity that includes spin-connection)
$$
\frac{i}{\alpha X} \sigma_1 \partial_T \psi - \sigma_2 \partial_X \psi + \frac{1}{2 X} \sigma_2 \psi - m \psi = 0 .   
$$
if I set $m=0$ and $\alpha=1$ and rearrange, I can write it as
$$
i \partial_T \psi = i \sigma_3 (X \partial_X - \frac{1}{2}) \psi = 0 .   
$$
Use the variable $\rho=\log X$ so that $X \partial_X = \partial_\rho$ and we can write
$$
i \partial_T \psi = i \sigma_3 (\partial_\rho - \frac{1}{2}) \psi = 0 ,   
$$
which, if we write $\psi = (u,v)$ splits up into
$$
\partial_T u = \left(\partial_\rho - \frac{1}{2}\right) u = 0 ,   
$$
$$
\partial_T v = -\left(\partial_\rho - \frac{1}{2}\right) v = 0 . 
$$
Solving these, or by messing around a bit with the plane wave solution from the Klein-Gordon case, I find the Rindler-coordinate massless Dirac equation solutions
$$
\psi = (1,0) e^{- i (k-\frac{1}{2} i) T} e^{-i k \log X} . 
$$
or
$$
\psi = (0,1) e^{- i (-k+\frac{1}{2} i) T} e^{-i k \log X} . 
$$
Now what exactly do these solutions mean? What is the on-shell condition? It appears to relate energy $\nu$ and momentum $k$ through, e.g.
$$
\nu = k-\frac{1}{2}i , 
$$
which is not great since at least one of energy or momentum must be complex in that case.

Furthermore, as a consequence of this, these solutions won't conserve probability. Perhaps that's not an issue as I only expect this solution to apply the in the right-Rindler wedge and it may be that what's happening in other parts of space-time make up for it?